# Using C++ model in QML, white page

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'am trying to send a object Cloud from C++ to QML. I want to show the name of my cloud in the QML using the model property.
I have no compilation error but when I execute the code severals infos are wrote :

> - QQUickView only supports loading of root objects that derive from
>     QuickItem

for this one i've tried to change all my QObject in QuickItem, without success.

> - If your example is using QML2, and the .qml file you loaded has 'import QTquick1,0' or 'import QT 4,7', this error will occur

I look for the import signaled, but I can't find any QtQuick1,0 or QT4
7 in my code.

Here my Cloud.h:

```
#ifndef CLOUD_H
#define CLOUD_H

#include <QObject>

class Cloud: public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
     Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
     Q_PROPERTY(QString description READ description WRITE setDescription NOTIFY descriptionChanged)

public:
    Cloud(QObject *parent=0);
    Cloud(const QString &name, const QString &description, QObject *parent=0);

    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);

    QString description() const;
    void setDescription(const QString &name);

signals:
    void nameChanged();
    void descriptionChanged();

private:
    QString m_name;
    QString m_description;
};

#endif // CLOUD_H
```

My Cloud.cpp

```
#include "cloud.h"
#include <QDebug>


Cloud::Cloud(QObject *parent)
    :QObject(parent)
{

}

Cloud::Cloud(const QString &name, const QString &description, QObject *parent)
    :QObject(parent), m_name(name), m_description(description)
{
}
QString Cloud::name() const{
    return m_name;
}
void Cloud::setName(const QString &name){

    if(name != m_name){
        m_name = name;
        emit nameChanged();
    }
}
QString Cloud::description() const{
    return m_description;
}
void Cloud::setDescription(const QString &description){
    if(description != m_description){
        m_description = description;
        emit descriptionChanged();
    }
}
```

My main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>

#include <qqml.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickitem.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickview.h>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "cloud.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<Cloud>("Sky", 1,0,"Cloud");


    QList<Cloud*> cloudList;
    cloudList.append(new Cloud("Cumulus Mediocris", "super nuage brocoli"));
    cloudList.append(new Cloud("Cumulus Towering", "super nuage tour"));
    cloudList.append(new Cloud("Cumulonimbus", "Gros nuage pas content"));

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(cloudList));

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And finally my main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2


ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    Rectangle{
        width:10;height:10
        color:"red"
        anchors.left : parent.left
        anchors.top:parent.top
    }

    ListView{
        width:100;height:100

        model: myModel
        delegate:Rectangle{
            height:25
            width:100
            color:"pink"
            Text{text:model.modelData.name}
        }
    }
}
```

To write this code I took a look to [Models and views in QtQuick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html) and [Using C++ Models with QtQUick View](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html)

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your main function. `QQuickView` is a quick way to display a QML scene in a window (`QQuickView` is itself a subclass of `QQuickWindow`). In your QML, the root object is `ApplicationWindow`. You cannot display a window inside a window.

The solution is to switch to `QQmlApplicationEngine`:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine view;
QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(cloudList));
view.load(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));
```

The second problem is with your model. `ListView` would understand a `QList<QObject*>`, but not a `QList<Cloud*>`. Just change the declaration to:

```
QList<QObject*> cloudList;
```

Comment: Ok I understand now, thank you. Does that mean it would work if instead of writting my ListView in the main.qml, I would write it in an other qml file ?

Comment: No, the problem is that the root element in your QML is `ApplicationWindow`. It should work if you used e.g. `Rectangle`